# Track Changes to MySQL table using Node.js

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to integrate node.js app into an existing PHP/MySQL system. `node-mysql` is used to allow node.js to access the MySQL database. A table named `tableA` in the MySQL database updates with new data every 10 minutes.

**Problem:** Using node, I need the node server to continuously check `tableA` for changes whenever `tableA` gets updated. What is a good way to achieve this?

I am thinking if I used `setInterval(checkDb(tableA), 10*60*1000)`, or an infinite loop, the `checkDb`query function may not coincide with the database update.

I also happen to be using `socket.io` so will a good method be for the PHP system to `emit('dbUpdated')` to the node server if it is even possible for PHP to send a message to node.js?

**Node Code**

```
var dbCheckQueue = function(callback) {
    client.query('SELECT * from tableA',
                    function(error, results, fields) {
                        if error
                            throw error;
                        callback(results);
                    });
}

// 10mins-interval checking of table
setInterval(function() {
    dbCheckQueue(function(results) {
        console.log('Fresh meat!')
    });
}, 10*60*1000);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally you would trigger the event from the where ever the update is being made from after completion.

Since you are using sockets you could create an "Events" connection or similar (authenticate or some other method to indicate it is connecting to trigger an event) which would connect to your socket and trigger an update and disconnect. This could be called from anywhere regardless of platform as long as you are able to create the connection. Once connected the script would send whichever command you want to be triggered and disconnect/finish the updating process.

You could either do this directly from where the update is made or setup a trigger on mysql with sys_exec() to execute another script which does the same as above.

Comment: How can I trigger it from PHP? Maybe just a simple method, because all I need is to send a 1-way message.

Comment: You would use socket_connect (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-connect.php) and related functions (socket_send) to connect and send your message.